# Laravel 5 relationships many to many with two tables

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to build a relationship on the same table over a pivot table.
I have two tables: `companies` (id) and a table `company_budgets` (id, company_id, sponsor_id, budget).
I need the folowing relationships:

- A company from companies table can sponsor multiple companies from companies table
- A company from companies table can have multiple sponsors from companies table

I tried this with different variations

```
public function sponsors() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Company','company_sponsors','company_id','sponsor_id')->withPivot('budget');
}

public function companies() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Company','company_sponsors','sponsor_id','company_id')->withPivot('budget');
}
```

but...

The next question would be how to retreive the data from pivot table?
How to query if a company is sponsored and how if the company is sponsoring?

I would like to query my tables something like this:

```
SELECT
companies.id AS "Company ID",
companies.`name` AS "Sponsoring company name",
company_sponsors.sponsor_id AS "Sponsored company ID",
(SELECT companies.`name` FROM companies WHERE companies.id = sponsor_id) AS "Sponsored company",
company_sponsors.budget AS "Sponsored budget"
FROM company_sponsors
INNER JOIN companies ON companies.id = company_sponsors.company_id
WHERE companies.id = 33;


SELECT
companies.id AS "Company ID",
companies.`name` AS "Sponsored company name",
company_sponsors.company_id AS "Sponsor ID",
(SELECT companies.`name` FROM companies WHERE companies.id = company_id) AS "Sponsor company name",
company_sponsors.budget AS "Sponsoring budget"
FROM companies
LEFT JOIN company_sponsors ON company_sponsors.sponsor_id = companies.id
WHERE companies.id = 10;
```

Comment: Take a look at this [Thread](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/441#issuecomment-14213883)

Comment: @Maraboc Thank you for the link. I saw it. I think I have problems with the controller not with the relationship. I got the solution for first half (first SQL) with the help from Laracasts user. I'll post the answer when I solve the second one.